# VB.NET Radio Button Handler Code running twice

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a group of `RadioButtons` in VB.NET. I would like to create one function that will handle all of them together. My code is below.

```
    Private Sub employmentStatusChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,_
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnEmployed.CheckedChanged, _ 
          rbtnUnemp.CheckedChanged, rbtnStudent.CheckedChanged, rbtnRetired.CheckedChanged
    If rbtnEmployed.Checked Then 
        Dim employ As New Employer
        employ.ShowDialog()
    ElseIf rbtnStudent.Checked Then
        Dim stud As New Students
        stud.ShowDialog()
    ElseIf rbtnRetired.Checked Then
        Dim employ As New Employer
        employ.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

This function works fine the first time I click a button. The problem comes when I click on a different button. It fires once for the first button's changed state (from checked to unchecked) and then again for the second button (unchecked to checked).

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. However, sender is the radio button that was clicked. Just check the state of that. If sender.Checked is False, return from the event handler.