# How to get a information from a listbox to textboxes with radio buttons

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, radio-button

I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have two radio buttons one for a new user a the other for an existing user. The new user radio button takes the information input into the textboxes and adds to the list box. The existing user button is supposed to take the line selected in the listbox and break it up then put it back into my textboxes. I have written code for the radio buttons but they are not working properly. How can I get the information to process correctly and show in the textboxes? I have tried a split and a function but this was unsuccessful. Can anyone help? This is what I have for the radio buttons so far I can post the rest of the code if you need me to.

```
Private Sub rbtnNew_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.CheckedChanged
    lstCustomer.Items.Add(RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtAddress.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtCity.Text.ToUpper))

End Sub

Private Sub rbtnExisting_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnExisting.CheckedChanged
    Dim name1 As String
    Dim address2 As String
    Dim city2 As String
    Dim output() As String

    name1 = txtName.Text
    address2 = txtAddress.Text
    city2 = txtCity.Text
    output = Split(lstCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString(), ",")

    txtName.Text = output(0)
    txtAddress.Text = output(1)
    txtCity.Text = output(2)



    lstResults.Items.Clear()
    txtChairs.Clear()
    txtSofas.Clear()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

The radiobutton checkedchanged event may be trigger either it is checked or unchecked. Make sure check the value/attribution of the radiobutton in the event function.

**Edit**: Do you have the error-checking code for the case that listbox has no items at all? Since no item is seleced in listbox will cause ListBox.SelectedItem return null or something which the Split() function can not handle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In addition, using the string manipulation function provided by the system, such as join(), concat().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Check the size/length of the resulting string array from split().

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?   Private Sub rbtnNew_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.CheckedChanged

        If rbtnNew.Checked = True Then
            lstCustomer.Items.Add(RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtAddress.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtCity.Text.ToUpper))
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Hard to read it the way your comment formatted the code but yeah, that's basically it. You can actually handle both radio buttons in the same checkedchanged event as well.

Comment: The error still says that there is no location for the output. I can't select the name from the listbox for it to seperate and go back to the text boxes. I am explaining the best way I can but I hope you understand what I am talking about. would it help if I sent you the program so you could see the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "You can't select the name from the listbox for it to separate .."? You can not focus on listbox to choose an item, or your function does not split the string of item caption/label into multiple fields?

Comment: Also you may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4091476/4192181) to check the correct radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the radiobuttons are very difficult to manage when they have the AutoCheck property set to True. Anyway I give you a couple of possible solutions:

Solution #1 (AutoCheck property set to True):

```
Private Sub rbtnNew_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.CheckedChanged

    Static wasInvoked As Boolean

    If Not wasInvoked Then

        If rbtnNew.Checked Then
            lstCustomer.Items.Add(RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtAddress.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtCity.Text.ToUpper))
        Else
            If lstCustomer.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then

                wasInvoked = True
                rbtnNew.Checked = True
                wasInvoked = False

                MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer from the list.")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub rbtnExisting_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnExisting.CheckedChanged

    If rbtnExisting.Checked Then

        Dim name1 As String
        Dim address2 As String
        Dim city2 As String
        Dim output() As String

        name1 = txtName.Text
        address2 = txtAddress.Text
        city2 = txtCity.Text
        output = Split(lstCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString(), ",")

        txtName.Text = output(0)
        txtAddress.Text = output(1)
        txtCity.Text = output(2)


        lstResults.Items.Clear()
        txtChairs.Clear()
        txtSofas.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Solution #2 (RadioButtons's AutoCheck property set to False):

```
Private Sub rbtnNew_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.CheckedChanged
    rbtnExisting.Checked = Not rbtnNew.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnExisting_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnExisting.CheckedChanged
    rbtnNew.Checked = Not rbtnExisting.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.Click

    If Not rbtnNew.Checked Then
        rbtnNew.Checked = True
        lstCustomer.Items.Add(RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtAddress.Text.ToUpper) & " , " & (txtCity.Text.ToUpper))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnExisting_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnExisting.Click

    If Not rbtnExisting.Checked Then

        If lstCustomer.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then

            MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer from the list.")
        Else
            rbtnExisting.Checked = True

            Dim name1 As String
            Dim address2 As String
            Dim city2 As String
            Dim output() As String

            name1 = txtName.Text
            address2 = txtAddress.Text
            city2 = txtCity.Text
            output = Split(lstCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString(), ",")

            txtName.Text = output(0)
            txtAddress.Text = output(1)
            txtCity.Text = output(2)


            lstResults.Items.Clear()
            txtChairs.Clear()
            txtSofas.Clear()
        End If
    End If
```